Swift: How to call a `completionHandler` from `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in a different scope
I have an app that listens to silent push notifications from my server while being in the background (via didReceiveRemoteNotification) to perform some network operations using URLSession.data.task. I'm new to Swift and I'm working on an existing codebase that nests multiple requests when a push is received in this fashion:
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
   //do some others URLSession.shared.dataTask operations
}.resume()

My didReceiveRemoteNotification looks like this:
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
            handlePush(userInfo: userInfo, metric: Metric.ALAPPBGPushFetchRequested)
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
        
    }

The Problem, when the silent push is received,completionHandler is called before all other URLSessions are completed. Ideally, I would have to call completionHandler from within those URLSession once those requests are resolved. I cannot just pass the reference of the completionHandler because there isn't a direct hierarchy that allows me to pass it down (handlePush triggers some other listeners, etc).
What could be a good solution to use this completionHandler from a different scope other than the original one? I thought about storing the completionHandler in a global variable and then using it but I'm getting unexpected exceptions sometimes, does not seems reliable, unless I'm just doing poor swift. I also wouldn't want to refactor the chain of calls that happens after handlePush because most of them are sensor listeners that eventually calls those URLSession.

There's no magic fix.  Either handlePush needs to accept a completion closure of its own that invokes completionHandler or, depending on your minimum iOS target, make handlePush async and await it. Either way, handePush needs to be aware of when all the work is complete.
